Subscriptions policy: Violation of Subscriptions policy
I am a developer, working on an Application which has Subscriptions and today I get "Subscriptions policy: Violation of Subscriptions policy" on my app, along with the warning that if I didn't fix it, it will be removed. I have fixed the issue and added two separate builds for that as well both of the builds got approved and working fine. I have added all the guidelines about the Trial period, what happens after trial period ends and how can a user cancel his/her subscription. But I am still seeing the policy violation in my app. That a really important app and I am worried that it will get removed on May 1. What should I do next to resolve this issue?

add full info so we can help you
